# OpenModelica overdetermined system when using a custom block

Tags: openmodelica

In OpenModelica I want to customize the behavior of a spring over a prismatic joint. For this I made a custom block which extends on the 'PartialCompliant' interface.
The input force is compared to pretension force. If the input force is higher than the pretension force, a spring is pushed in, until a stop is reached. The displacement is calculated with a spring constant. I want to couple the displacement and forces to the prismatic joint using flanges. When I try to run the model, i get an error that there is one more equation compared with the amount of variables. How can i find the variable/equation which causes this overdetermiation.

The code i use for the custom block can be seen below:

```
block ElastoGapTest
extends Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Interfaces.PartialCompliant;
import Modelica.Units.SI;

// Variables
parameter SI.TranslationalSpringConstant c(final min=0, start=100) "Spring constant";
parameter SI.TranslationalDampingConstant d(final min=0, start=1) "Damping constant";
parameter SI.Position s_rel0=0 "Unstretched spring length";
constant Real LimUp = 0.1;
constant Real LimLow = -0.1;
constant Real FVoor = 1000;
Real Fin;
Real FLim;
Real s;

equation
Fin = flange_a.f;
FLim = c\*LimUp;

// if statement to compare to input foce
if abs(Fin) \< FVoor then
flange_b.s = Fin;
f = 0;
else
 flange_b.s = (abs(Fin) - FVoor)/c;
if flange_b.s \> LimUp then
flange_b.s = LimUp;
f = abs(Fin) - FVoor - FLim;
else
f = 0;
end if;
end if;

// Negative if negative input
if Fin \< 0 then
flange_b.s = -flange_b.s;
f = -f;
end if;

end ElastoGapTest;`
```

The model I try to implement my custom code into is as follows:

```
model TestModel   
inner Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.World world   
Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Joints.Revolute revolute   
Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.Body body(m = 10)  
Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyBox bodyBox(r = {1, 0, 0})   
Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Joints.Prismatic prismatic(useAxisFlange = true) 
ElastoGapTest elastoGapTest(c = 100, d = 10)
equation   
connect(world.frame_b, revolute.frame_a)
connect(bodyBox.frame_a, revolute.frame_b)
connect(prismatic.frame_b, body.frame_a)
connect(prismatic.frame_a, bodyBox.frame_b)
connect(elastoGapTest.flange_a, prismatic.support)  
connect(elastoGapTest.flange_b, prismatic.axis)
end TestModel;
```